# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at System.DateTimeParse.Parse

Tags: c#

sqlparameters for date of birth

```
 SqlParameter dayParameter = new SqlParameter("@day", SqlDbType.Int);
            SqlParameter monthParameter = new SqlParameter("@month", SqlDbType.Int);
            SqlParameter yearParameter = new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.Int);
```

converting of day, month and year `

```
 dayParameter.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(0, 2)));
        monthParameter.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(3,2)));
        yearParameter.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(6,4)));
```

class jfunction

```
 public class Jfunctionparents
{
    public static string GetSystemDate()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
    }
    public static string GetSystemTime()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Today.ToString("t"));
    }
```

shows this error on submitting

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear - the string you passed in was not a valid format.  Please post an example of the values you're trying to convert - we're not mind readers.

Comment: Your code should not works from string representation of the date and in particular not hard-coded for a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
dayParameter.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(0, 2)));
```

looks logically wrong, system cannot convert the output of `Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(0, 2)` to `DateTime` since it is a string of length 2.

I think what you want here is just the day, so there is no need to convert `Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(0, 2)` to `DateTime`

the statements should look like:

```
dayParameter.Value = Int32.Parse(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(0, 2));
monthParameter.Value = Int32.Parse(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(3,2));
yearParameter.Value = Int32.Parse(Jfunctionparents.GetSystemDate().Substring(6,4));
```

Comment: thank you @ErikFunkenbusch, updated the code.